# Is there a defined product support lifecycle for Wildfly / JBoss AS?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm looking for dates until when patches for known vulnerabilities will be delivered for the products mentioned above. I found the same for RedHat's JBoss Enterprise Application Platform, but not for JBoss AS or Wildfly.

Here's an [example](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/#Life_cycle_dates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding JBoss Middleware, there is a [product update and support policy](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes).

- For long-life products, JBoss offers *Full support* for 4 years, *Maintenance support* for 3 years and *Extended-life support* for other 3-6 years.

Although you can imagine JBoss engineers working on the underlying Widlfly software creating patches and solutions for all the time of the *Full Support*, there is not any guarantee. In addition, note that the version numbers of the JBoss EAP are not the same of the used by Wildfly.

- The JBoss EAP v 7.0 (released in 2016, for Java EE 7) uses the Wildfly 9.x (alias "Kenny", released in 2015)
- The JBoss EAP v.7.1Beta (released in 2017) uses Wildfly 10.x (released in 2016).

Today (September 6, 2017), reviewing the [Issue Tracker for Wildfly](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/WFLY/summary), almost all the *updated issues* in the last week are related to the last versions: 20 are for the version 11.x, 3 for the 12.x-Beta, and 1 for the 8.x. Other 31 do not specify a version. All the *resolved issues* (9/9) in the last week are related to the version 11.x.

I think you must consider to use one of the last two GA versions of Wildfly. The community is more active in these versions. According to the [Wildfly governance page](http://wildfly.org/governance/), they deliver a new final major version in around a nine month cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any guaranteed support for community projects like WildFly and JBoss AS. Commercial support is only available for commercial products like JBoss EAP.

Comment: I understand, but shouldn't there be at least some kind of "road map", until when the current release is planned to be developed further?